# Google Play Developer Console: Can't reply to user comments

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-console

Slashgear says that [Now all developers in the Google Play Store will be able to respond to any and all comments or reviews](http://www.slashgear.com/google-play-store-update-allows-developers-to-reply-to-all-review-10264791/).

But I can't figure out how. In the developer console, here is the UI I have to see reviews:

[image]

No hidden button appear on mouseover or anything.

- Is the answer button hidden somewhere?
- Do I have to change a setting to enable it?
- Has the feature not been deployed yet?

Comment: it's not available for all yet. Slashgear had jumped the gun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was before, but now all Google Play developers can reply to user reviews. 
check this article:
[All Google Play Developers Can Now Reply to User Reviews](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/all-google-play-developers-can-now.html)

---

In order to reply on reviews, please follow these steps posted [Here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en) in Developer console help center:

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Ratings & Reviews > Reviews.
4. In the "Reply to this review" box, type your response.
5. Select Publish Reply.

Screenshot for clarification:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This feature is currently only available to select developers, not all. I also do not have this ability.

From [Developer Console Help](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en):

> We are also piloting a new developer response feature, where select
>   developers can publicly reply to any comment once. In such a case, an
>   email will be sent to the commenting user with an option to update the
>   comment or contact the developer directly through the support email
>   address provided in the Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: @user99572isfine See edit ;)

Comment: cool, you got my upvote

Comment: Hi, is it still available only to selected developers? Is there a way to request that feature?

Comment: @Frank: See the [other answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/99380/88163)